# How to show that the inequality with exponents is true

Tags: inequality, logarithms

In part of a question in my homework I'm doing, I need to show that:

$$ \log(n) > \sqrt [n]{n} $$

Is this a correct a correct manipulation:
$$n > e^\sqrt [n]{n}$$

Thank you in advance!

**edit:**
that's a good point that it works only for n>4, and I forgot to mention that n is a natural number ({1,2,...})

Comment: are we given any conditions on $n$?

Comment: n is natural number ({1,2,...}

Comment: Doesn't it fail for $n=1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, $\log(1) > \sqrt[1]1$ is wrong, and as well n=2,3,4.  So let's suppose $n \geq 5$ (it holds for $n=5$).

Put it as 
$$
(\log (n))^n
> n
$$

Then use induction,
$$
%(\log (n+1))^{n+1} >=(\log (n) + \log(1 + 1/n))^{n+1}
(\log (n+1))^{n+1} >(\log (n))^{n+1} = \log(n) (\log (n))^{n} \geq  n \log(n)
$$

Where the last one holds by induction.

Now show

$$\log(n) > 1 + 1/n$$ which holds for $n=5$, and then also for larger n since the log is increasing with n and $1/n$ is decreasing with n. 
So one can continue 
$$
%(\log (n+1))^{n+1} >=(\log (n) + \log(1 + 1/n))^{n+1}
(\log (n+1))^{n+1}  \geq  n \log(n)
> n (1 + 1/n) = n+1
$$
Done. $\quad \quad \Box$

Comment: Perhaps expanding on this would be a good thing?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/780593)

Comment: @TheCount The answer is there now. People should care posting their questions correctly.

Comment: I certainly agree. Similarly, I agree that answers should be complete. That sounds brusk, but it is not meant to be.

Answer (score 4):

(In the true spirit of stackexchange:)

Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof by induction since $n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

$n=1$, we have:

LHS = $\log 1$ = 0

RHS = $1 > $LHS hence the statement is incorrect.

Comment: where is the induction?

Comment: It was coming, then it failed for $n=1$, so I didn't need to go further

Comment: @mrnovice I don't know why, but that comment made me laugh *a lot*.

Comment: @mrnovice +1 for the fun.

Answer (score 1):

True, lets manipulate the inequality $ \ln(n) > n^{\frac{1}{n}}$  which can be turn into $\ln(\ln(n)) > \frac{1}{n} \ln(n)$ (because $\ln(a^b) = b \ln(a)$)

And then multiply by $n$ we get that $n \ln(\ln(n)) > \ln(n)$ when $\ln(\ln(n)) > 1$ we can reduce it to $n > \ln(n)$ which can be turn into $e^n > n$ which is true and can be proven by induction $n=1$ => $e^1 \approx 2.718 >1 $ now assume its true for $e^{k} > k$ prove that $e^{k+1} > k+1$ which is $e^{k}*e >k+1$ which is $k*e > k+1$ using the assumption,which can be reduces to $2k>k+1$ and its true when $k>1$, last step is to see when $\ln(\ln(n)) >1$   which is just when $n > e^{e^{1}} \approx 15.15$ ,so the inequality is true when $n >15$ and when $n \leq 15$ a check is enough to show that its true when $n >4$

Comment: how did you you do the manipulation from: ln(ln(n))>1 to n>ln(n) ?

Comment: @Yaron Scherf i wanted to reduce right side so i asked when $\ln(\ln(n)) >1 $ because then it will be like $n \ln(\ln(n)) > n*1 = n > \ln(n)$

Answer (score 0):

Andreas said to holds for $5$ , which is not true ; Ahmad has the correct concepts but uses the $\log_e$ while the question uses base $10....n ≥16$ for the inequality to hold , then one can take the derivative of both sides and see the left increases and right decreases for $n ≥ 16 \cdots$ thus it holds for $n ≥ 16$

Comment: Please check that it IS TRUE for n=5: $\log(5) - \sqrt[5] 5 = 1.6094  -     1.3797 =  0.2297$

Comment: A strong indication that the question doesn't use $\log_{10}$ is that the OP himself reformulates it in his question to $n > e^\sqrt [n]{n}$, so he uses base $e$.